# Make .bat File To Search in All .txt

Tags: batch-file

I use this code to search in specific input:

How do I make this code search for all .txt without asking for a specific file?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the 'findstr' command.  Check it's help 'findstr /?' for a full list of options but I would use it like this:

```
set /p text=what text do you want to find?
set /p outfile=where to place the results? 
findstr /sipnc:"%text%" *.txt > "%outfile%"
```

Edit: added output file redirection to more closely match your original script.

Updated script below (in a batch file):

```
@echo off
set /p test=what text do you want to find?
set /p outfile=where to place the results?
echo.>%outfile%
for /f %%f in ('dir /s /b *.txt') do find /i "%text%" < "%%f" >> "%outfile%"
```

Comment: i want my code searches for all .txt and get the wole line and export the result as my code and now your code add the location of the word i want only to show the line